# OnKeyup jquery validate method not working selectbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form and used jquery validate plugin. I used both focusout & keyup functions for trigger errors. Its working fine all inputs, but not working in select box.

when we move to next field without fill, it will show alert. After the alert visible, if started filling, alert message hided when it met requirement.

But it doesn't work in selectbox. Just open select box and close select box without selecting any. Now move to next field or submit. It show alert message. This time select any option. But alert message still showing even we chose a option.

How to make selectbox validation like inputs?

My script

```
$(function(){
    $("form").validate({
        ignore: ":hidden",
        onclick: false,
        //onfocusout: false,
        onsubmit: true,
        onkeydown: false,
        inlineErrors: true,
        onfocusout: function (element) {
                    this.element(element);
                 },
        onkeyup: function(element) {
                $(element).valid()
            },        
        rules: {
            input: {
                required: true,
                minlength:5
            },
            select: {
                required: true
            },

        },
        messages: {
            input: "Required",
            select: "Required",
        },
    });
});
```

My form

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="input" required>
<select name="select" required>
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="one">One</option>
<option value="two">Two</option>
<option value="three">Three</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Here my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4nqpd3uv/

Comment: Please learn how to properly use jsFiddle regarding the including of libraries and external resources.

Answer (score 0):

> How to make selectbox validation like inputs?

1. You've broken it by setting `onclick` to `false`, but you probably didn't realize it because you also have the following issues:
2. There are absolutely no such options called `inlineErrors` and `onkeydown`.  You cannot just make up words or make blind guesses: [Refer to the documentation for the only valid options](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate), and remove these lines.
3. There is no reason to have `ignore: ':hidden'`, because this value is exactly the same as the default value.  Remove this line.
4. You cannot set `onsubmit` to `true`.  This is already the default behavior and the [documentation specifically states that *"true is not a valid value"*](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#onsubmit) for the `onsubmit` option.  You can only set it to `false` to disable, or a function that over-rides the default.  When you set this option to `true`, you override the underlying default function with `"true"`, which could lead to unpredictable behavior.  Remove this line.
5. Apparently you want "eager" validation, so you've set your custom `onfocusout` and `onkeyup` functions to validate immediately.  The problem is your usage of `.valid()` within `onkeyup`.  You should be using `.element()`, just like you did within `onfocusout`.  The `.element()` method is the more proper way to do this from *within* `.validate()`.  Only use `.valid()` *outside* of `.validate()`, otherwise, you create the potential to throw your JavaScript into a loop in certain situations.
6. There is no reason to have the `required` attribute inline within your HTML.  Your `required` rule is already declared within the `rules` object for both fields.  It's redundant, so you can remove these HTML5 attributes.

Setting `onclick` to `false` is the root cause of your complaint.  This removes the validation trigger when you choose an option from the `select` element.  You are not allowed to set it to `true`, so remove this line.  (*The official documentation for `onclick` is missing information about `select` elements so I've submitted an edit to fix this.*)

Working Code:

```
$("form").validate({
    // REMOVE THESE COMMENTED LINES
    // ignore: ":hidden",    // <- exactly the same as DEFAULT
    // onclick: false,       // <- disables select validation - ROOT PROBLEM!
    // onfocusout: false,    // <- duplicate, see below
    // onsubmit: true,       // <- must NOT set to true!
    // onkeydown: false,     // <- NO SUCH OPTION!
    // inlineErrors: true,   // <- NO SUCH OPTION!
    onfocusout: function(element) {  
        this.element(element); // <- eager validation
    },
    onkeyup: function(element) {     
        this.element(element); // <- eager validation
    },
    rules: {
        input: {
            required: true, // remove inline HTML5 'required' attribute
            minlength: 5
        },
        select: {
            required: true  // remove inline HTML5 'required' attribute
        }
    },
    messages: {
        input: "Required",
        select: "Required",
    },
});
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/qu2jgj22/](https://jsfiddle.net/qu2jgj22/)**